# Capitalized L replacing lowercase L for inline code tags?

Tags: support, design

This is driving me absolutely bananas so I have to ask about it at this point. I created [a post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/388053/spawned-under-water-in-bedrock-edition) that contains multiple inline code tags containing the letter `L` in it's lowercase form. However, these lowercase `L`s appear, at least visually, like they've been translated to uppercase:

[image]

As a developer, I have myself assuming that this is an effect of the font used, and that it is by design. However, as an end user it's driving me up the wall... Is this a bug, or is this by design to ensure that readers can tell the difference between `L` and `I`? I noticed it doesn't happen here on meta.

---

<sub>***Note**: I purposely excluded the [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) tag because it could be by design, which, I would absolutely understand. Once an answer confirms/denies this, the [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) tag will be added or remain excluded as indicated by the confirmation/denial.*</sub>

Comment: Related: [What's the font used in code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36176/whats-the-font-used-in-code-blocks). It's likely the font. If you zoom in, the lower case l is slightly curved, and gives the appearance of being uppercased while normally zoomed

Comment: @Wondercricket I firmly believe it's a variance in font; however, my issue there is that the font family for code tags when inspected both here and on the primary site, is `ff-mono`. Meanwhile, the lowercase `l` doesn't curl here like it does on the primary.

Comment: I think it's related to how some fonts in that variable appear in italics, in particular. See *`l`* vs *`L`* vs `l` vs `L`